# Cosmos c# problem with file system vfs cannot register

Tags: c#, cosmos

I get this error:

> Error
> Exception: System.Exception: Error compiling method 'SystemStringDudoOSCommandsFileExecuteSystemStringarray': System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'aType') DudoOS  C:\Users\k\source\repos\DudoOS\DudoOS\IL2CPU    1

And I do not know how to fix it.

```cs
using DudoOS.Commands;
using System;
using Sys = Cosmos.System;
using Cosmos.System.FileSystem;
using Cosmos.System.FileSystem.VFS;

namespace DudoOS
{
    public class Kernel : Sys.Kernel
    {
        private CommandManager commandManager;
        private CosmosVFS vfs;

        protected override void BeforeRun()
        {
            this.vfs = new CosmosVFS();
            VFSManager.RegisterVFS(this.vfs);

            this.commandManager = new CommandManager();
        }

        protected override void Run()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Dudo caka na tvoje prikazi \n>> ");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                string response = this.commandManager.ProcessInput(input);
                Console.WriteLine(response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Sys = Cosmos.System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Cosmos.System.FileSystem.VFS;

namespace DudoOS.Commands
{
    public class File : Command
    {
        public File(string name) : base(name) { }

        public override string Execute(string[] args)
        {
            string response = " ";

            switch (args[0])
            {
                case "create":
                    try
                    {
                        Sys.FileSystem.VFS.VFSManager.CreateFile(args[1]);
                        response = $"Dudo vyvoril subor: {args[1]}, neuveris vytvoril sa! :D";
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        response = $"Dudo nezvladol vytvorit subor: {args[1]} Code: {e.ToString}";
                        break;
                    }
                    break;

                case "delete":
                    try
                    {
                        Sys.FileSystem.VFS.VFSManager.DeleteFile(args[1]);
                        response = $"Dudo omylom zmazal subor: {args[1]}";
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        response = $"Dudo zabudol ako sa maze subor: {args[1]} Code: {e.ToString}";
                        break;
                    }
                    break;

                case "createdir":
                    try
                    {
                        Sys.FileSystem.VFS.VFSManager.CreateDirectory(args[1]);
                        response = $"Dudovi pomohola sova vytvorit adresar: {args[1]}";
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        response = $"Dudovi nikto nepomohol vytvorit adresar: {args[1]} code: {e.ToString}";
                        break;
                    }
                    break;

                case "removedir":
                    try
                    {
                        Sys.FileSystem.VFS.VFSManager.DeleteDirectory(args[1], true);
                        response = $"Dudo: Co sa stalo? kde je adresar: {args[1]}?";
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        response = $"Dudo: kto mi pomoze zmazat adresar: {args[1]}? code: {e.ToString}";
                        break;
                    }
                    break;

                case "writestr":
                    try
                    {
                        FileStream fs = (FileStream)Sys.FileSystem.VFS.VFSManager.GetFile(args[1]).GetFileStream();

                        if (fs.CanWrite)
                        {
                            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(args[2]);
                            fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                            fs.Close();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            response = "Dudo nemoze zapisovat do tohoto suboru";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        response = e.ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                    break;

                case "readstr":
                    try
                    {
                        FileStream fs = (FileStream)Sys.FileSystem.VFS.VFSManager.GetFile(args[1]).GetFileStream();

                        if (fs.CanRead)
                        {
                            byte[] data = new byte[256];

                            fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                            response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            response = "Dudo nemoze precitat tento subor, proste stratil okuliare...";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        response = e.ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    response = "Dudo nevie aky prikaz mas na mysli";
                    break;
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to fix it, but vfs does not showing as registered

Answer (score 0):

You must create a VFS using C#'s `new`.
Put this before and outside the `BeforeRun` function.

> `Sys.FileSystem.CosmosVFS vfs = new Cosmos.FileSystem.CosmosVFS();`

On another note, remove:

> this.vfs = new CosmosVFS();

In your namespace `DudoOS.Commands`, you do **not** need to create another vfs, as one is created before that code runs. You can just use `File`, `Directory`, `StreamWriter`, `StreamReader`, etc.